# Error fetching entity by Entity Id from Google App Engine backend for Android app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa

I am using Google App Engine as a backend for my Android app.I am able to insert entities into the datastore using the method(auto-generated when i created the endpoint for my Note class)

```
/**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param note the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertNote")
public Note insertNote(Note note) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        if (containsNote(note)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.persist(note);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return note;
}
```

So to use this method from my Android app and insert an Entity i use this from my `AsyncTask class`

```
try {
      Note note = new Note();

      String descrptn = descriptionTF.getText().toString();
      String email = emailTF.getText().toString();
      String noteID = new Date().toString();

      note.setDescription(descrptn);
      note.setId(noteID);
      note.setEmailAddress(email);      

      Note result = endpoint.insertNote(note).execute();

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

It's all sunshine and rainbows till i try to retrieve the entity from the datastore.I get `FATAL Exception:...Caused by Java.lang.NullPointerException: required parameter id must be specified`

This is the method to call when trying to retrieve an Entity(Auto-generated also)

```
/**
 * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
 * @return The entity with primary key id.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getNote")
public Note getNote(@Named("id") String id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Note note = null;
    try {
        note = mgr.find(Note.class, id);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return note;
}
```

and this is what am trying from my Android activity

```
 try {
      Note newNote = new Note();
      String noteID = newNote.getId();
      Note newResult = endpoint.getNote(noteID).execute();
      String descrptn = newResult.getDescription();
      String email = newResult.getEmailAddress(); 


      descriptionTV.setText(descrptn); 
      emailTV.setText(email);


  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return (long) 0;
    }
```

Can any help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

In your Android activity, I see the following code :

```
  Note newNote = new Note();
  String noteID = newNote.getId();
  Note newResult = endpoint.getNote(noteID).execute();
```

If you see, you are creating an instance of the Note() class in the first line. This still means that other attributes of the Note class and which includes `Id` are null. So actually in your second line, you are assigning `null` to `noteID` and that is being passed along to the endpoint `getNote` method. Hence the server side gets a null for the Id and hence throws the exception.

In your Android code, you might be showing a list of notes in some `ListActivity` and then when you are selecting one of the notes, you will be able to get the ID from the `selectedItem`. So you should pass this value instead, to retrieve the details from the Server endpoint implementation.

Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: Hi.But the method `getId()` is supposed to return the `id` which already exists in the datastore.

Comment: Please look at the code again. You are instantiating a class there and nothing is initialized yet.